# Python: Variable not taken into a formula

Tags: python, while-loop

Hello all good souls out there.
I'm trying to solve a problem for a mortgage calculator. This calculator should return the possible amount to borrow based on client's cashflow. However, I'm posting only the problematic slice of code here.
The case is, that if I add the value of 1000 to the variable `possible_loan_amount` it does that, but it is not taken further into the formula for the next variable `stress_rate_payment`. (I know that, because I've tried it with "if" statement instead of "while" and it was added to `possible_loan_amount`.) Therefore if I run the while loop, it runs into an infinite loop and nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong on this one?
The goal is to add 1000 to the variable `possible_loan_amount` until the difference between `stress_rate_payment` and `cashflow` is not less or equal 10.

```
from numpy import pmt


interest_rate = 1.5
years = 30
cashflow = 916.30

def test(interest_rate, years):
  possible_loan_amount = 10000
  stress_rate_payment = pmt(((interest_rate+2)/100)/12, 12*years, possible_loan_amount) * (-1)
  difference = stress_rate_payment - cashflow
  if difference < 0:
    difference = difference * (-1)
  while difference > 10:
    possible_loan_amount += 1000
  return possible_loan_amount, stress_rate_payment


print(test(interest_rate, years))
```

Thank you all.

Comment: The variable `difference` is never getting updated in the while loop, so it always maintains the first value which triggered the while loop and gets stuck. You want to move the first three lines + the conditional which are used to calculate `difference` into the while loop so that it updates.

Comment: This is because when it is performing the computation it is not pointing to a reference of the variable, instead using the explicit value of the variable and then creating a new object in memory with the results. It will not update dynamically, unlike dictionaries or other mutable datatypes.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz Thank you bro'. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the variable `difference` within the `while` loop. Currently the variable `difference` is being set just once and then never changed, so in case `difference` is greater than 10, you create an infinite loop always adding 1000 more to `possible_loan_amount` but `difference` never gets recalculated